# C++ reading text file line by line stops partway through

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a file with 16,900,000 lines, each line contains 10 numbers (mix of int and floats).  I'm trying to read this file line by line, modify each line slightly, and write to a series of new files.  The code below works on a laptop running Windows Visa, but when I run it on a desktop running Windows 7, the output file does not contain all the data from the input file. The number of lines in the output file varies from 2500 to 40,000.

I've commented out all of the processing, and writing to files, and just write every 100th line to cout, the last line to print isn't the last line of the file.

```
// skipping code prior to the loop
// only including minimal code that reproduces the problem
ifstream infile((srcdir+filename).c_str()); 
string line;
int lcount=0;

while(getline(infile,line)){
    if(line.find("#")==string::npos){
        lcount++;
        if(lcount%100==0){
            printf("Generating tiles for %s: %d lines processed\n",filename.c_str(),lcount);
        }

    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there a maximum buffer size that I might be overflowing?
2. Can anyone see a problem with my code?
3. Is there any reason this would work fine on Windows Vista, but not on Windows 7?

Comment: I need to send this to a customer that has Windows 7, and windows 8 machines.  It needs to work on those as well.

Comment: This is a hard problem to replicate...

Comment: You probably have to, at least, post a complete program. There's nothing obviously wrong in your code...

Comment: If your file doesn't have 'exactly' a multiple of 100 lines that would cause your code to not show the exact last line.

Comment: @Diniden, Yes, I know that.  I know my file has 1,6900,000 lines.  The most I've ever gotten printed to the screen is 1.1M (so far from all lines have been read)

Comment: @Richard In the last line that you get printed, what's the value of `lcount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While trying to create a minimal full program that would reproduce the problem, I found the culprit.

I'm trying to secure the executable with the keylock dongle that my company is using.  When I removed the check for the dongle, the entire file was read.

Answer (score 0):

In your question there is very little information. But I will put here my guesses:

I don't think `lcount` is in being incremented at the correct place in code. It get incremented only if `'#'` is not in the `line` (I'm guessing this is some sort of comment). But a line starting (o containing) `'#'` has to be counted too. So your code should be:

```
while(getline(infile,line)){
    lcount++;  // Increment every time.
    if(line.find("#")==string::npos){
        if(lcount%100==0){
            printf("Generating tiles for %s: %d lines processed\n",filename.c_str(),lcount);
        }

    }
}
```

On the other hand, you should activate isftream exceptions in order to see whats going on, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) how to doit.

Comment: I only want to count the non-comment lines. Thanks for the link to exception handling.

Comment: @Richard Ahh, ok, but keep in mind when testing that lcont don't will be equal to16,900,000 .

Comment: There are 1,690,000 non-commented lines.  I found the solution, it's still a problem, but a different one.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, for the next question try to write exactly what you mean. In this question you can read clearly: *I have a file with 16,900,000 lines...* you should write: *I have a file with 16,900,000 UNCOMMENTED lines...* and of course explain what a comment is to you.